# Quisiera saber por que me aparece este error?

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined index: fila in C:\xampp\htdocs\teatro\biblioteca.php
>   on line 26,Notice: Undefined index: puesto in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teatro\biblioteca.php on line 27, Notice: Undefined
>   index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\teatro\index.php on line 94, Notice:
>   Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\teatro\index.php on line 86,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]        
        
        
        
        Uso de formularios para transferencia

```
<!-- paste this code into your webpage -->
<link href="css/tablecloth.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/tablecloth.js"></script>
<!-- end -->

<style>

body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    font:70% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color:#555;
    line-height:150%;
    text-align:left;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#057fac;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;
}
h1{
    font-size:140%;
    margin:0 20px;
    line-height:80px;   
}
h2{
    font-size:120%;
}
#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:680px;
    background:#fff;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
#content{margin:0 20px;}
p.sig{  
    margin:0 auto;
    width:680px;
    padding:1em 0;
}
form{
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:.2em 20px;
    background:#eee;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<div id="container">
    <h1>Teatro</h1>

    <div id="content">


    <!-- construimos la tabla dinamica... --> 

        <?php include 'biblioteca.php'?>

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <div cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <th>ESCENARIO</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>   
            </tr> 
                             </div> 
                            <td></td>
                                <td><?php echo $puestos_teatro['puestos'][$puesto]; ?></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>

            </tr>               
            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $puestos_teatro['filas'][$fila]; ?></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>                               
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $puestos_teatro["filas"]["fila1"]; ?></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>                           
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>                               
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                                <td>4</td>
                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>                               
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                                <td>5</td>
                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>                               
            </tr>

        </table>

        <form method="POST" action="biblioteca.php">  

        Fila: <input type="text" name="fila"  />
            <br>
            <br>
        Puesto: <input type="text" name="puesto"  />
        <br>
        <br>
            Reservar <input type="checkbox" name="reservar" />
        <br>
            Comprar <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $puestos_teatro['estado_puestos']['reservado']['vendido']; ?>" name="comprar" />
        <br>
        Liberar <input type="checkbox" name="borrar"  />

        <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />

        <input type="submit" value="Borrar" />
           </form>       

        <p> Desarrollado por: William Leonardo Ortegón Aguirre</p>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
```

//archivo requerido por el formulario biblioteca.php

```
        $puestos_teatro = array('estado_puestos'=>array(
            'reservado'=>'R',
            'vendido'=>'V',
            'libre'=>'L'),
                        'filas' => array(
                                'fila1'=>'1',
                                'fila2'=>'2',
                                'fila3'=>'3',
                                'fila4'=>'4',
                                'fila5'=>'5'),
                                    'puestos' => array (
                                            'puesto1'=>'1',
                                            'puesto2'=>'2',
                                            'puesto3'=>'3',
                                            'puesto4'=>'4',
                                            'puesto5'=>'5'));


        foreach ($puestos_teatro as $estados) {  

        $fila = $_POST["fila"];
        $puesto = $_POST["puesto"];
        }
?>
```

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: fila in C:\xampp\htdocs\teatro\biblioteca.php on line 26,Notice: Undefined index: puesto in C:\xampp\htdocs\teatro\biblioteca.php on line 27,
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\teatro\index.php on line 94, Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\teatro\index.php on line 86, gracias por responder

Comment: No es un error, es una `Notice`, una información de que en el `$_POST` no existen los índices `fila` y `puesto`. En realidad tú tienes dos inputs con name `fila` y `puesto` en el formulario, pero al parecer tu formulario **no se está enviando correctamente** al PHP que lo recoge con `POST`. Puedes ver lo que hay dentro del POST haciendo: `var_dump($_POST);` **Además**, la manipulación que haces, intentando obtener los valores del POST dentro de un bucle no parece tener ningún sentido ¿?

Comment: Prueba en obtener tus valores de la siguiente manera `$fila = isset($_POST["fila"])  ? $_POST["fila"] : '';` lo mismo con `$puesto`, es aconsejable resetear los variables con los que vas a trabajar, también podrías añadir al principio de tu código `$fila = $puesto = NULL;` ya que en ocasiones podrían estar vacíos tus `inputs` y por ello el `notice`.